# How to watch file changes with ts and js build

Tags: node.js, typescript, apollo-server, fastify, nrwl

I have a project with fastify, apollo server fastify and nx. I want to add a script to build my code and run the js files. the problem is that if I make any changes in ts file it wont recognize to re run the js files. what should I do?
btw I can't use ts-node for runnig my ts code because I have used custom libraries and I have to first build my code.

my current script:

```
"serve": {
      "executor": "@nrwl/workspace:run-commands",
      "options": {
        "commands": [
          "tsc -p tsconfig.app.json -w",
          "tsc-alias -p tsconfig.app.json -w",
          "nodemon ../../dist/apps/server/authentication/index.js"
        ],
        "cwd": "apps/authentication",
        "parallel": true
      }
    }
```

Comment: You can run nodemon diretly with typescript file. `nodemon path/to/ts/index.ts`. Or as an alternative you can run tsc with `-w` option to watch for file changes, and in a separate terminal you can run nodemon.

Comment: @UgurEren thank you, but as I said I can't run my ts code because I have to build my packages/libraries first

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made a custom executor, I hope this help someone else:

```
    "start": {
      "executor": "@nrwl/workspace:run-commands",
      "options": {
        "commands": [
          "nodemon -e ts,graphql --exec \"nx run server-authentication:start-nodemon\""
        ],
        "cwd": "apps/server/authentication",
        "parallel": false
      }
    },
    "start-nodemon": {
      "executor": "@nrwl/workspace:run-commands",
      "options": {
        "commands": [
          "nx run server-authentication:ts-build",
          "node ../../../../dist/apps/server/authentication/src/index.js"
        ],
        "cwd": "apps/server/authentication",
        "parallel": false
      }
    },
    "ts-build": {
      "executor": "@nrwl/workspace:run-commands",
      "options": {
        "commands": [
          "tsc -p tsconfig.app.json",
          "tsc-alias -p tsconfig.app.json",
          "ncp src/schema ../../../../dist/apps/server/authentication/src/schema",
          "ncp .env ../../../../dist/apps/server/authentication/src/.env"
        ],
        "cwd": "apps/server/authentication",
        "parallel": false
      }
    },
```